# Rails relation for 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models which look like these:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :Clan
end

class Clan < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users, primary_key: 'id', foreign_key: 'clan_id'
 belongs_to :clan_lvl
end

class ClanLvl < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :clan, primary_key: 'id', foreign_key: 'lvl_id'
end
```

Class `User` has `clan_id` and class `Clan` has `lvl_id` so I think my realation should be good.

And I can access data like `current_user.clan.something` but it seems that rails cant make the relation to the third model because `current_user.clan.clan_lvl` is always nil.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should also explain how the models are initialized and saved, probably something in the forms.Also, have you set the strong parameter permissions correctly?

Comment: Models have been generated using scaffold, and i use data from seeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :clan
end

class Clan < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users
 belongs_to :clan_lvl, foreign_key: 'lvl_id'
end

class ClanLvl < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :clan, foreign_key: 'lvl_id'
end
```

Comment: #Anezio Campos This seems to work. Thanx. As i see all I needed was `belongs_to :clan_lvl, foreign_key: 'lvl_id'` How does that make the difference?

Comment: By default the belongs_to was looking for clan_lvl_id and couldn't find it. You can read more about it here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to. Please mark the answer as correct too